# Multiple comparisons in an if statement using the logical OR operator is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am checking in following way, But its not working. When I am using single statement it's working.  i.e (NodeName !== "Active")

```
   function ClientCandidateMenuNodeClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
        var node = eventArgs.get_node();
        var NodeName=node.get_text();
        if( (NodeName !== "Active") || (NodeName !== "Recently Added") || (NodeName !== "Added") )
         {   
           if (NodeName != null)
           {
              alert(NodeName);
           }
        }
          node.toggle();
    }
```

Comment: Here NodeName is coming correctly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. If the value of `NodeName` is `"Recently Added"` the first thing that happens is a comparison to `"Active"` which evaluates to `true` (because they are not the same). Because the first condition evaluates to true the whole condition is considered true and the `alert` is executed.

You need to change your "ors" to "ands" (notice that I've removed all those parentheses too... you don't need them here):

```
if (NodeName !== "Active" && NodeName !== "Recently Added" && NodeName !== "Added") {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The NodeName is *always* not "Active" or not "Recently Active" or not "Added". You want to use

```
if (NodeName !== "Active" && NodeName !== "Recently Added" && NodeName !== "Added" && NodeName != null) {
    alert(NodeName);
}
```

or

```
if (!(NodeName === "Active" || NodeName === "Recently Added" || NodeName === "Added") && NodeName != null) {
    alert(NodeName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if( NodeName !== "Active" || NodeName !== "Recently Added" || NodeName !== "Added" ) {   
  alert(NodeName);
}
```

Comment: Why remove the `null` check?